# Azure WAAD WebApp to WebApp Access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm working on a WAAD WebApi which calls another WebApi.

I created two apps in my WAAD. I can connect from one WebApi to the other. But when I create a third app I can also get a token for the third app.

Is there a way to prevent App1 to get a token for App3 and only get a token for the App2 app.

I know there is an option to create a delegated permission for App2 and add this permission to App1 but as far as I can see this won't prevent App1 from getting a token for App3.

I know my question is a bit cryptic, but feel free to ask more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not cryptic. The answer however is: No. 
Azure AD allows all services that are registered in the directory to acquire Client Credential Flow tokens for each other (service to service access tokens). In the resource service code, you need to "authorize" calls per the ObjectId or AppId of the calling service/app.

Giving the ability to gate such access at token issuance time is a capability that we are considering to include in AAD - however I recommend that you unblock by doing this simple ACL check at the resource service.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Next questions pops up. Can I add groups to the app or anything other (via the Graph API) so I can manage the authentication in AAD?

Comment: You can add an app (service principal) to a group via Graph API - if that's what you meant by adding groups to app.

Comment: So you can add client apps to groups to "grant privilege". When they access the resource app it queries Grap API to determine the group membership of the app to authorize access.

Comment: When I read this document : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974486.aspx it states that only Contact, Group, and User objects are supported as members of a group. Can I just add the object Id of an application and than later call the memberof with the object Id?